# How to see changes in a react component after state change without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently working on adding create option to my fronted react app, As I first want to test the fronted's working , I used localStorage for storing my data. Based on the length of data, that I receive from the localStorage I will render two different components (if the length is zero, then one else the other) . I am using useEffect() hook to get the data and to prevent the error "localStorage is not defined". I have a component called ServicesComponent.jsx which has form and once submitted will push the dataValues(which is a JSON type state btw) into an array called dataValues which is stored in the localStorage. In another component called onBoard I retrieve these values from the localStorage and render them in rows. I have a problem with this, The servicesComponent is a popup component in the onboard page, I want to see changes once the form is filled and the popup is closed in the onboard page. Here are my codes:

ServicesComponent.jsx:

```
const Configure = (props) => {
    let dataValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('DataValues') || '[]') || [];
      const [DBToggle, setDBToggle] = useState(true);
      const toggleDB = () => {
        setDBToggle(!DBToggle);
      };
      const [Data, setData] = useState({
        source:
          companies[localStorage['index_1']]['company'][localStorage['index_2']]
            .name,
        stage: '10',
        status: 'Completed',
        creator: 'Srinivasan D',
        runtime: '1D 5Hrs',
        estTime: 'Apr 18,2023',
        createdDate: 'Apr 18,2023',
        updatedDate: 'Apr 18,2023',
        transferSize: '1 TB',
      });
    
      const handleDataChange = (event) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        setFormData((prevFormData) => ({ ...prevFormData, [name]: value }));
      };
    
      const handleDataSubmit = (toggleSource, setTrigger, setSource) => {
        dataValues.push(Data);
        localStorage.setItem('DataValues', JSON.stringify(dataValues));
        localStorage.setItem('DataLength', dataValues.length);
        toggleSource(setTrigger, setSource);
        window.location.reload()
      };
return props.trigger ? (
<div
  className="popup"
  onClick={() => props.toggleSource(props.setTrigger, props.SetSource)}
>
/* Irrelevant Code */
</div>
```

In the above code the setSource function is nothing but used for closing the popup and resetting the popup to stage 1 as it is a two-stage popup.

Onboard.js:

```
export default function Onboard() {
  const [dataValues, setdataValues] = useState('');
  const [redFlag, setredFlag] = useState(0);
  const [Loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    let val;
    val = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('DataValues') || '[]') || [];
    setdataValues(val);
    let flag;
    flag = localStorage.getItem('DataLength');
    setredFlag(flag);
    setLoaded(true);
  }, [localStorage.getItem('DataValues')]);
  console.log(redFlag);
return (
    <div>
      {Loaded ? (
        <div>
          {redFlag > 0 ? (
            <div>
               {*/ Data Values is rendered here */ }
             </div>
           : ''}
         </div>
        }
     </div>
```

I would like to know how to fix this issue.